# MySQL: how to make multiple table fulltext search

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I want to integrate the MySQL fulltext search function in my PHP site.

I have the following problem now.

```
SELECT *
FROM testtable t1, testtable2 t2
WHERE MATCH (
t1.firstName, t1.lastName, t1.details, t2.firstName, t2.lastName, t2.details
)
AGAINST (
'founder'
);
```

And i have the error code:

```
#1210 - Incorrect arguments to MATCH
```

Do you know why and how to solve it?

Thanks very much!

Edit:

I adopt RageZ's method:

```
SELECT *
FROM testtable t1, testtable2 t2
WHERE MATCH (
t1.firstName, t1.lastName, t1.details
)
AGAINST (
'founder'
) OR MATCH( t2.firstName, t2.lastName, t2.details) AGAINST (
'founder'
);
```

And I have a new question. If i want to find the content which are :

```
AGAINST('founder', 'initiator', 'employee');
```

How to write the query?

Ok, i know against can only have one criteria.

```
AGAINST('founder');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think since full text search use some specific indexes you should separate table by `OR`

```
SELECT *
FROM testtable t1, testtable2 t2
WHERE MATCH (
t1.firstName, t1.lastName, t1.details
)
AGAINST (
'founder'
) OR MATCH( t2.firstName, t2.lastName, t2.details) AGAINST (
'founder'
);
```

Comment: that smells like a cartesian product to me (but then, I have no experience with "match / against") .. shouldn't there be a "restriction" (aka join) that provents this?

Comment: @thanks RageZ, if the elements in AGAINST are multiple, how to handle that?

Comment: your would have to copy the pattern multiple time

Comment: @lexu: the error message is specific about the syntax in the against not being correct. if mysql would have ran crazy I would have bet like you ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
AGAINST('founder initiator employee');
```

or you can use [boolean mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html) with more good stuff