# MySQL full text search, why am I getting Incorrect arguments to MATCH

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT 
* 
FROM 
company c
INNER JOIN 
city ci ON ci.city_id = c.city_id
INNER JOIN 
state s ON s.state_id = c.state_id
WHERE 
MATCH (
c.name, ci.name, c.zipcode, s.name
)
AGAINST (
'los angeles'
)
```

Comment: This question is very related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378366/mysql-how-to-make-multiple-table-fulltext-search  Although I don't think they are dupes, since this question doesn't "pre-know" about a possible problem due to `JOIN`.

Answer (score 18):

All columns in `MATCH (...)` must be from the same table, because they must be fulltext indexed, and MySQL cannot create one index for data in multiple tables.

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem and solved it like this:

```
SELECT 
* 
FROM 
company c
INNER JOIN 
city ci ON ci.city_id = c.city_id
INNER JOIN 
state s ON s.state_id = c.state_id
WHERE 
   MATCH (c.name) AGAINST ('los angeles')
OR MATCH (ci.name) AGAINST ('los angeles')
OR MATCH (c.zipcode) AGAINST ('los angeles')
OR MATCH (s.name) AGAINST ('los angeles')
```

But as I see, You are searching in simple fields like 'name' and 'zipcode'. As for me, it would be better to use `LIKE` and just concatenate them

```
SELECT 
* 
FROM 
company c
INNER JOIN 
city ci ON ci.city_id = c.city_id
INNER JOIN 
state s ON s.state_id = c.state_id
WHERE 
CONCAT_WS (' ', c.name, ci.name, c.zipcode, s.name)
LIKE ('%los angeles%')
```

Comment: Be careful using CONCAT_WS like that will match results like a company named "Hellos" in a city named "Angeles". An unlikely bug to encounter, but still a potential issue.

Comment: This should really be marked as the answer.

This is a very clever way around the single table limitation.

Moving from MySQL MyISAM to MariaDB InnoDB with Full Text Search this is a quick way to  "port" your original queries.