# MySQL optimize OR with multiple tables

Tags: mysql

i'm trying to find a better solution, because the actual query takes too long.

lets assume you have 3 tables: tasks, adresses, persons
now we have a string like "tobias london" - we will split the string by spaces and get ["tobias","london"]
(of course we could have a more complex string with more words)

now we want all tasks, that has matches in adresses OR persons
AND ALL words must match

actual query example:

```
SELECT
  tasks.task_id
FROM
  (
    tasks,
    (SELECT
      adress_id AS id,
      'adress_id' AS typ
    FROM
      adresses
    WHERE adresses.city LIKE 'tobias%'
      OR adresses.street LIKE 'tobias%'
    UNION
    SELECT
      person_id AS id,
      'person_id' AS typ
    FROM
      persons
    WHERE persons.name LIKE 'tobias%') f0,
    (SELECT
      adress_id AS id,
      'adress_id' AS typ
    FROM
      adresses
    WHERE adresses.city LIKE 'london%'
      OR adresses.street LIKE 'london%'
    UNION
    SELECT
      person_id AS id,
      'person_id' AS typ
    FROM
      persons
    WHERE persons.name LIKE 'london%') f1
  )
WHERE (
    f0.typ = 'adress_id'
    AND tasks.adress_id = f0.id
    OR f0.typ = 'person_id'
    AND tasks.person_id = f0.id
  )
  AND (
    f1.typ = 'adress_id'
    AND tasks.adress_id = f1.id
    OR f1.typ = 'person_id'
    AND tasks.person_id = f1.id
  )
```

this is extremely slow, because of the OR within the WHERE-clauses (and this is just an example with 2 words)

anybody know how to make it better than this?

EDIT: as requested a small db-fiddle:

> ```
> CREATE TABLE `adresses` (
>   `adress_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>   `street` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
>   `house_number` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
>   `postal_code` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
>   `city` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
>   PRIMARY KEY (`adress_id`),
>   KEY `street` (`street`),
>   KEY `postal_code` (`postal_code`),
>   KEY `city` (`city`)
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
>
> /*Data for the table `adresses` */
>
> insert  into `adresses`(`adress_id`,`street`,`house_number`,`postal_code`,`city`) values 
> (1,'first','1',12345,'London'),
> (2,'second','2',23456,'Paris'),
> (3,'third','3',34567,'Okawa'),
> (4,'fourth','4',45678,'Berlin'),
> (5,'fiveth','5',56789,'ABCDE'),
> (6,'sixth','6',65535,'DFGHJH');
>
> /*Table structure for table `persons` */
>
> CREATE TABLE `persons` (
>   `person_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>   `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
>   PRIMARY KEY (`person_id`),
>   KEY `name` (`name`)
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
>
> /*Data for the table `persons` */
>
> insert  into `persons`(`person_id`,`name`) values 
> (1,'Anna'),
> (2,'John'),
> (3,'Michel'),
> (4,'Olivia'),
> (5,'Pavel'),
> (6,'Peter'),
> (7,'Sarah'),
> (8,'Tobias');
>
> /*Table structure for table `tasks` */
>
> CREATE TABLE `tasks` (
>   `task_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>   `person_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
>   `adress_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
>   `description` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
>   PRIMARY KEY (`task_id`),
>   KEY `person_id` (`person_id`),
>   KEY `adress_id` (`adress_id`)
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
>
> /*Data for the table `tasks` */
>
> insert  into `tasks`(`task_id`,`person_id`,`adress_id`,`description`) values 
> (1,1,2,''),
> (2,2,3,''),
> (3,3,4,''),
> (4,5,6,''),
> (5,4,1,''),
> (6,1,4,''),
> (7,3,3,''),
> (8,8,1,'');
>
>
> SELECT
>   tasks.task_id
> FROM
>   (
>     tasks,
>     (SELECT
>       adress_id AS id,
>       'adress_id' AS typ
>     FROM
>       adresses
>     WHERE adresses.city LIKE 'tobias%'
>       OR adresses.street LIKE 'tobias%'
>     UNION
>     SELECT
>       person_id AS id,
>       'person_id' AS typ
>     FROM
>       persons
>     WHERE persons.name LIKE 'tobias%') f0,
>     (SELECT
>       adress_id AS id,
>       'adress_id' AS typ
>     FROM
>       adresses
>     WHERE adresses.city LIKE 'london%'
>       OR adresses.street LIKE 'london%'
>     UNION
>     SELECT
>       person_id AS id,
>       'person_id' AS typ
>     FROM
>       persons
>     WHERE persons.name LIKE 'london%') f1
>   )
> WHERE (
>     f0.typ = 'adress_id'
>     AND tasks.adress_id = f0.id
>     OR f0.typ = 'person_id'
>     AND tasks.person_id = f0.id
>   )
>   AND (
>     f1.typ = 'adress_id'
>     AND tasks.adress_id = f1.id
>     OR f1.typ = 'person_id'
>     AND tasks.person_id = f1.id
>   )
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> | task_id |
> | ------: |
> |       8 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e6314cbd6db03a4512e1dfa7db284508)*

Comment: Have you tried [Full-Text Search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html)

Comment: you tink of: WHERE tasks.person_id=persons.person_id AND tasks.adress_id=adresses.adress_id
AND MATCH (persons.name, adresses.street, adresses.city) AGAINST ('tobias' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) AND ... (2nd match-condition)?
tried it, but seems incorrect (Incorrect arguments to MATCH)
i also don't know if the restrictions would be ok, for example if the search string would be "tobias london 123" i would also check for adresses.hous_number

Comment: just read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610812/mysql-full-text-search-why-am-i-getting-incorrect-arguments-to-match that said all cols from a fulltext search must be of the same table, so it is not an option

Comment: you still have to use union

Comment: the problem is not searching in persons or adresses, that is relativly fast
the problem is the join of 2 or more tables to 2 or more columns of the main-table

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins).   After that you might create a [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0), just about 10 records is enough (I will add some more records, before looking into optimizing the query )

Comment: @Luuk added the db-fiddle, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Redesign the schema.  The use of `typ` to pick between two table is a very bad idea in a Relational Database.  (As you are finding out.)

After that, it may be useful to have a `FULLTEXT` index on the columns that could have "tobias%" or "london%".  But the problem then comes because the address and person name are in different tables.

If you had both in the same table:

```
SELECT ...
    WHERE MATCH(firstname, last name, address, city)
          AGAINST("+tobias* +london*" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

And have this index on the table

```
FULLTEXT(firstname, lastname, address, city)
```

(Be aware of limitations of word length, etc.)

**Another approach**

Consider making a separate table (`Search`) with perhaps two columns:

- `words` - a mashup of all the things that users might search on (names, city, etc)
- `task_id` (or whatever is the necessary key) -- for joining to the other table(s)

Then use it (for example) thus:

```
SELECT ...
    FROM Search
    JOIN ... ON Search.task_id = ...
    WHERE MATCH(Search.text) AGAINST ("+word1 +word2" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
    ...
```

It helps to eliminate any 'short' words when building the query.

This technique takes extra effort when inserting rows.  And there is redundant data in the database.  (This is a no-no, but is often necessary for performance.)

Comment: any idea about the redesign? since persons are persons and adresses are adresses ... they have to be in separate tables i think?

Comment: @mech - I added to my answer.

Comment: tahnk you, but since this is just a basic example (there are way more tables that could be involved) i can't put all together in one table (there are tasks with persons, adresses, services, materials, billing-informations, messages, and so on)
so it seems there is no "good" way

Comment: @mech - I added "Another Approach".